# Drag-and-drop into contentEditable DIV in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm stuck with drag-and-drop handling in Firefox.

Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5nqRX/

There are two textareas and two contentEditable divs on a page.

0) If you drag text from the first textarea and drop it to the second one, text if copied. <-- in IE/Chrome it's moved

1) If you drag text from the textarea and drop it to the contentEditable div, nothing happens. <-- in IE/Chrome it's moved

2) If you drag text from the first contantEditable div and drop it to the second one, text completely disappears (removed from the first div, and didn't appear in the secod one) <-- in IE/Chrome it's moved

WTF with default Firefox's drop handling? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Don't think you're missing anything. It looks like Firefox's text dragging with contenteditable is a bit flaky.

Comment: @Teemu Securing your webpage by not using `contenteditable` is like a securing images by blocking context menus.

Comment: @oleq I agree, also I can't remember posted this comment, though it can be found from my "Activity" list... Too much beer maybe : ).

Comment: I wrapped the the contentEditable divs in another div (also content editable) and it works but behaves weeeirrrd. If you want to copy the text you have to hold 'alt' (osx) but if you don't use alt the text will be moved and the div from where you are taking the text will disappear. [http://jsfiddle.net/5nqRX/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/5nqRX/11/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known firefox issue. You can't do anything about it.